# how to find most common entry in dictionary of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I have a dictionary that's two levels deep. That is, each key in the first dictionary is a url and the value is another dictionary with each key being words and each value being the number of times the word appeared on that url. It looks something like this:

```
dic = {
    'http://www.cs.rpi.edu/news/seminars.html': {
        'hyper': 1,
        'summer': 2,
        'expert': 1,
        'koushk': 1,
        'semantic': 1,
        'feedback': 1,
        'sandia': 1,
        'lewis': 1,
        'global': 1,
        'yener': 1,
        'laura': 1,
        'troy': 1,
        'session': 1,
        'greenhouse': 1,
        'human': 1

...and so on...
```

The dictionary itself is very long and has 25 urls in it, each url having another dictionary as its value with every word found within the url and the number of times its found.

I want to find the word or words that appear in the most different urls in the dictionary. So the output should look something like this:

> The following words appear x times on y pages: list of words

Comment: Can you provide a full example input and output?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Counter isn't quite what you want. From the output you show, it looks like you want to keep track of both the total number of occurrences, and the number of pages the word occurs on.

```
data = {
    'page1': {
        'word1': 5,
        'word2': 10,
        'word3': 2,
    },
    'page2': {
        'word2': 2,
        'word3': 1,
    }
}

from collections import defaultdict
class Entry(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pages = 0
        self.occurrences = 0
    def __iadd__(self, occurrences):
        self.pages += 1
        self.occurrences += occurrences
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} occurrences on {} pages'.format(self.occurrences, self.pages)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Entry {} occurrences, {} pages>'.format(self.occurrences, self.pages)

counts = defaultdict(Entry)

for page_words in data.itervalues():
    for word, count in page_words.iteritems():
        counts[word] += count

for word, entry in counts.iteritems():
    print word, ':', entry
```

This produces the following output:

```
word1 : 5 occurrences on 1 pages
word3 : 3 occurrences on 2 pages
word2 : 12 occurrences on 2 pages
```

That would capture the information you want, the next step would be to find the most common `n` words. You could do that using a heapsort (which has the handy feature of not requiring that you sort the whole list of words by number of pages then occurrences - that might be important if you've got a lot of words in total, but `n` of 'top n' is relatively small).

```
from heapq import nlargest
def by_pages_then_occurrences(item):
    entry = item[1]
    return entry.pages, entry.occurrences
print nlargest(2, counts.iteritems(), key=by_pages_then_occurrences)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you should use a `Counter` for this:

```
from collections import Counter
print sum((Counter(x) for x in dic.values()),Counter()).most_common()
```

Or the multiline version:

```
c = Counter()
for d in dic.values():
    c += Counter(d)

print c.most_common()
```

---

To get the words which are common in *all* of the subdicts:

```
subdicts = iter(dic.values())
s = set(next(subdicts)).intersection(*subdicts)
```

Now you can use that set to filter the resulting counter, removing words which don't appear in every subdict:

```
c = Counter((k,v) for k,v in c.items() if k in s)
print c.most_common()
```

Comment: `from collections import Counter`

Comment: Same reason you can't use `dict`s and `list`s as `dict` keys: __mutability__. You do get an `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`, don't you?

Comment: Oh, I might have misunderstood what you were wondering about, wonder out loud in a question, please! :)

Comment: ahh, it's because the implementation does `self[key] + other[key]` without checking that the `other` actually *has* that key.  Still, it seems that they should be able to relax the assertion that `Counters` can only be added to other `Counters`

Comment: @Kimvais -- I'm wondering why you couldn't do `Counter((1,1,2,3)) + {1:3}`

Comment: It seems that the above just counts the words regardless of which url they came from, I only want to count the words that are common throughout all the urls. So only the words that appear at least once in every url should be counted.

Comment: @LucasSilva -- I didn't realize that the words had to be in every URL.  It's not hard to make that happen though.  See my update.